# check the file has zip extension

Tags: perl, perl-module

My script :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl
use POSIX qw(strftime);
use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Long;

##input parameters

my ($artifact,$package_id);
GetOptions("artifact=s" =>\$artifact,
       "package_id=i" => \$package_id);
if($artifact =~ /\.zip$/i)
    {
    chdir("/apps/checkout/artifactory/xxkintana/$package_id");
    unzip  $artifact;
 }
```

run :

./script.pl 4370177 test-1.0.zip

Error :

Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at ./script.pl line 21.

Please help me that to find whether its zip file or not. input file like test-1.0.zip

-Thnaks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're checking to see if `$artifact` ends in `.zip`, but you don't actually set it when calling the script.

```
./script.pl --package_id=4370177 --artifact=test-1.0.zip
```

I would suggest cleaning up the parsing of your options, so that you actually do some error checking.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use POSIX qw(strftime);
use Getopt::Long;

##input parameters

GetOptions(
    "artifact=s"   => \my $artifact,
    "package_id=i" => \my $package_id,
) or usage();

usage("Unknown arguments: @ARGV\n") if @ARGV;
usage("--artifact is required\n") if ! $artifact;
usage("--package_id is required\n") if ! $package_id;

if ($artifact =~ /\.zip$/i) {
    chdir("/apps/checkout/artifactory/xxkintana/$package_id");
    unzip  $artifact;
}

sub usage {
    my $message = shift;
    die "${message}Usage: ./$0 --artifact=<artifact> --package_id=<id>\n";
}
```

Finally, I would probably make additional error checking to ensure that the directory you're trying to `chdir` exists, that `$artifact` exists, and throw appropriate error messages for those and any more cases that you can think of.